# How to migrate off SQLDB service on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb, sqldb

IBM is pulling the SQLDB service on Bluemix. Does anybody know how I can move my stored data, what are my options in terms of service?

Comment: Shouldn't that be the answer to a question?

Comment: I made your question an answer and added a real question.

Comment: You can try IBM DashDB Transactional. It is 100% compatible with SQLDB and DB2. http://ibm.biz/dashdbtx_info Can migrate using Lift or Data Studio. Was released April 12th, 2016.

Comment: Also, you can look into Data Conversion Workbench, which lets you migrate to dashDB for Transactions, DB2 on Cloud, or any other DB2-based database: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/ibmdcw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Migration Options and Information

1. The migration options which we suggest are Compose PostgreSQL or DB2 on Cloud.  DB2 on Cloud is a self-managed offering.  Compose PostgreSQL Enterprise is offered as fully-managed or self-managed while the multi-tenancy version is only offered as fully-managed.  Compose will soon be delivered soon as an IBM Branded Service meaning that you will not need to have a separate account on Compose.io.
2. What are the plans for a free SQL Database Service?  We are moving away from offering free SQL Database services.  The Compose PostgreSQL multi-tenancy offering is a metered service so you pay for what you use.  If you have minimal usage you will find the charges are nominal.
3. What tools do you recommend for data migration?  We suggest looking at Dataworks Forge and Dataworks Lift as the tools to use for migration.

## Steps to Migrate

1. Export DDL from SQLDB
2. Apply DDL from SQLDB to target without triggers, stored procedures, and UDFs.  If you are using a tool like DataWorks Lift or DataWorks forge the DDL file will the input into the tool.
3. Migrate data from SQLDB to target.

## Exporting DDL from SQLDB

1. Sign-in with IBM ID, download free version of db2client
       - URL http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217
2. Get VCAP information for SQL Database from Bluemix.  Document the host name and database name.
3. On command line within db2client, execute the following commands:
       - db2 catalog tcpip node "any_name_you_want" remote "publicipaddress" server 500003
       - db2 catalog database "databasename" at node "the name from above"
       - db2look -d "database name" -i "user name from VCAP" -w "password from VCAP" -e -o "output file"
4. The output file will contain the DDL from SQLDB